# Show that $g_n(x)=nf(x+1/n)-nf(x)$ converges uniformly to $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $f$ be a real valued, continuous and differentiable function on the real numbers with $f'$ uniformly continuous. Show that $g_n(x)$ with $$g_n(x)=nf(x+1/n)-nf(x)$$ is uniformly convergent to the derivative of $f$.

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. If anyone could help me for this problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hint: $$g_n(x) = \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$$

Comment: "$g_n$ uniformly convergent to $f$" ?? Sure about that?

Comment: @Mark i cant understand please explain it.

Comment: If you write $g_n$ as I did, it's in the form of the [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient), a common way to define the derivative.  For this reason, it should be quite easy to show that $g_n\to f'$ (note that it's $f'$, not $f$) pointwise, so the only real work will to be to show that it does it uniformly.

Comment: @Mark i already show that $g_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent .but i cant get the inequality using derrivative of f is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Did sorry for that, it is deerivative of f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to combine the uniform continuity of $f'$ with the mean-value theorem in order to deduce what is called "uniform differentiability."  For any $h > 0$ we can use the MVT to find $0 < k < h$ such that 
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) = f'(x+k) - f'(x).
$$

For $\epsilon >0$ we pick $\delta >0$ such that $z,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|z-y| < \delta$ implies that $|f'(z)-f'(y) | < \epsilon$.  Then for $0 < h < \delta$ we use the above to estimate 
$$
\left\vert \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right\vert=  |f'(x+k) - f'(x)| < \epsilon
$$
since $0 < k < h < \delta$.  Since $x$ is arbitrary we find that 
$$
0 < h < \delta \Rightarrow \sup_{x } \left\vert \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right\vert < \epsilon.
$$

This is actually a stronger result than what you need.  I'll leave it to you to fit the two together.